# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running .class file with certain package

Tags: java, windows

Consider Some.java file
inside com/work folder. I have given the package name accordingly.

```
package com.work;
 
class Some{
    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I am able to compile this Some.java file and get the respective Some.class file,
But when I am trying to run the Some.class file with command **java Some**, considering I am in the work folder, I am getting the below error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.work.some
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.work.some
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not run this from the `work` folder. Go two levels up, then run

```
java com.work.Some
```

If this does not help, additionally set the classpath

```
java -classpath . com.work.Some
```

Comment: After setting the classpath it is running.
Thanks

Comment: The classpath points to the (list of) directory where Java should search for com/work/Some.class and other such files.